# Do bonfire ascetics cause the respawn of more bonfire ascetics and can I farm them in this manner?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I was wondering if, when a BA is used, does it cause any possible BA in the area to respawn? If so, would it be worthwhile to farm BAs in this manner?

Comment: Items on bodies will respawn. I'm not sure about chests because I've seen it both ways, it may just dependend on the chest.

Comment: @slow_excellence wooden chest items re spawn, metal chests don't.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the wiki goes you can. Everything will resporn except of iron Chests so if you know where to find a BA on the ground or in a wooden Chest it will resporn.

> Burning a Bonfire Ascetic also respawns the items found in the area
>   and respawn wooden chests and corpses BUT not iron chests. -wiki 
>   http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Bonfire+Ascetic

And you need a location that has more than 1 BA so that its actually possible to farm them.

> 3 can be found in an iron chest in Drangleic Castle after the Looking
>   Glass Knight fight near the elevators leading down into the Shrine of
>   Amana.
>
> 2 can be found in an iron chest in Aldia's Keep up the stairs in the
>   main hall with the skeletal dragon.
>
> 3 can be found in an iron chest in Dragon Shrine near the entrance.
>
> 3 can be found in an iron chest in Memory of Orro by rolling on to the
>   suspended platform after destroying the crane contraption on the
>   rooftop and then jumping into the hidden area.
>
> 3 can be found on a corpse in Cave of the Dead in the main area after
>   dropping down one of the holes.

-wiki 
http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Bonfire+Ascetic

So as far as I see the only possible way is the 3 after LookingGlassKnight and the Corpse in Cave of the Dead